# Round up function in excel

Tags: excel-formula

Agenda: I want to round up the **whole numbers (Number)** in the following format,

```
    If (LastDigitOfNumber=0)
    {
        Result=Number;
    }
    Else If (1<=LastDigitOfNumber<=3)
    {
        Result=Round down to nearest 10;
    }
    Else If (4<=LastDigitOfNumber<=6)
    {
          Result= Number as a multiple of 5;
          // for ex: if the number is 34, result=35
          // if number is 36, result=35
    }
    Else If (7<=LastDigitOfNumber<=9)
    {
          Result= Number rounded up to the nearest multiple of 10;
    }
```

Question: I am not sure how to achieve this with excel, if else function or rounding function in excel doesn't seem to work. Can anybody please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,10)=0,A1,
  IF(AND(MOD(A1,10)>=1, MOD(A1,10)<=3), FLOOR(A1/10,1)*10,
    IF(AND(MOD(A1,10)>=4, MOD(A1,10)<=6), FLOOR(A1/10,1)*10+5,
      IF(AND(MOD(A1,10)>=7, MOD(A1,10)<=9), CEILING(A1/10,1)*10,"X")
    )
  )
)
```

Results

```
A1=10  --> 10
A1=11  --> 10
A1=12  --> 10
A1=13  --> 10
A1=14  --> 15
A1=15  --> 15
A1=16  --> 15
A1=17  --> 20
A1=18  --> 20
A1=19  --> 20
A1=20  --> 20
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. I was trying in the mean while and was happy to find out about choose function in excel. I gave this formula in the cell and it worked, 

=IF(MOD(E5,10)=0,E5,E5+CHOOSE(MOD(E5,10),-1,-2,-3,1,0,-1,3,2,1,0))

Comment: Very nice. You should probably add your own answer with that formula and mark your answer as accepted to bring closure to your question

Comment: Sure i will. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for the above posted question,

=IF(MOD(E5,10)=0,E5,E5+CHOOSE(MOD(E5,10),-1,-2,-3,1,0,-1,3,2,1,0))

E5 is the cell number in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Just for interest, another way is
    =E5+SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(E5,10)={0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}),({0;-1;-2;-3;1;0;-1;3;2;1}))